# Modulo and infinity, why is $x\bmod\infty$ equal to $x$ for binary operations on integers and $x \in \Bbb Z$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, infinity, programming

*Disclaimer: I am a programmer and my mathematical skills are those of Discrete Mathematics as taught at universities. I am interested in the mathematical background of how we can define $x\bmod\infty$, to understand essentially why, in programming language design we make the choices the way we do.*

*I believe in mathematics you call this the binary modulo operation, where the operator returns the remainder of integer division.*

I thought it's such a simply question that I was surprised I couldn't find the answer at Math SE, so perhaps it isn't a mathematical question to begin with. A little background: yesterday we had a discussion at the [XSLT 3.0 WG](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/) about a [certain edge case](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=29760) and its expected outcome, and we seemed to remember that $x\bmod\infty = x$. But none of us was quick to find this definitively described anywhere.

Essentially, I am wondering about the reason why:

$$x\bmod\infty = x$$

With my limited skilss, I deduct that, in $x\bmod y$, as soon as $y$ gets bigger than $x$ it will always return $x$, so this should also be true for infinity, right? In other words, I think that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x\bmod n = x,  x \in \Bbb Z$$

And while we are at it, would this hold too?

$$x\bmod-\infty = x$$
$$0\bmod\infty = 0$$
$$0\bmod-\infty = 0$$
$$\infty\bmod\infty = \infty$$
$$-\infty\bmod\infty = -\infty$$
$$\infty\bmod-\infty = \infty$$
$$-\infty\bmod-\infty = -\infty$$

And the following seems logical, though I haven't found it definitively either:

$$\infty \bmod x = NaN$$
$$-\infty \bmod x = NaN$$

Comment: How do you define $x \pmod \infty$?

Comment: What has been commented on before is the tendency of programmers to use `mod` as a binary *operation* on integers, expecting it to produce a functional result, and the tendency of mathematicians to  use $\bmod$ to define *relations* among integers.  Naturally the point of view for XSLT standards who adhere more to the programmer perspective.

Comment: @hardmath: exactly. I used that MathJax symbol `\bmod`, assuming it would be the binary operation. I'm afraid that I have little understanding of what it would mean when you talk about _relations_ among integers. And talking of standards, I am not sure this is defined in IEEE-754.

Comment: You have to include n>x in the limit definition. Else x could also be that n.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is my question not clear? Care to elaborate (or edit my question) on what can be improved?

Comment: I did not cast a downvote, so perhaps I should not speculate about that, but you also picked up a vote-to-close (as unclear).  As a programmer and esp. a fan of XSLT, I'm sympathetic with the impulse to appeal to Math.SE to learn what $x \bmod \infty$ *ought* to mean.  It seems to me the programming issue has to do with supplying a default argument, and that an explanation of why $x \bmod \infty$ is mathematically un-meaningful won't advance your cause.  Still it might be "a teaching moment".

Comment: @hardmath: thanks, I have updated the question. I am interested in the _mathematical_ (or _arithmetical_) perspective, to understand why we choose a certain approach in programming language design. There's always a natural link between programming languages and mathematics. in fact, the IEEE 754 standard, on floating point arithmetics, was largely influenced by mathematicians.

Comment: @Denis, your answer seems to have turned in a comment. I am interested in the binary modulo (infix modulo) operator that returns the remainder of division by integers.

Answer (score 3):

Let's consider $x\bmod t$, for $t>0$; one of the used definitions for real $t>0$ is
$$
x\bmod t=x-t\left\lfloor\frac{x}{t}\right\rfloor
$$
If $0\le x<t$, we have $0\le x/t<1$, so $\lfloor x/t\rfloor=0$ and $x\bmod t=x$.

If $-t<x<0$, we have $-1<x/t<0$, so $\lfloor x/t\rfloor=0=-1$ and
$$
x\bmod t=x+t
$$

Thus you see that the definition $x\bmod\infty=x$ would only be reasonable for $x\ge0$.

However, if you use “truncated division”, the definition $x\bmod\infty=x$ would also be reasonable for $x<0$.

See [Modulo operation on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation#Remainder_calculation_for_the_modulo_operation) for the different definitions of the mod operation. You'll also see that different programming languages use different conventions. In any case the definition $x\bmod \infty=x$ for $x\ge0$ fits any of the conventions.

Comment: Wikipedia's disambiguation page for [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulus) is also good context.  The Latin *modulus* means (unit of) measurement, and the reduction of a length by multiples of a "modulus" gives a nice geometric interpretation of [Euclid's division algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_division).